# want to control 3d objects with python

Tags: python, 3d, ursina

[image]

when ever I am running this both the windows are not opening side by side

```
from ursina import *
import tracker


# define a video capture object 

app = Ursina()
player = Entity(model='cube', color=color.orange, scale_y=2)
if app.run():
    tracker.track()
app.run()
```

The tracker code

```
import cv2

def track():

 vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 
 while True:
 
     ret, frame = vid.read() 
     cv2.imshow('frame', frame) 
       
     # the 'q' button is set as the 
     # quitting button you may use any 
     # desired button of your choice 
     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
         break
   
 # After the loop release the cap object 
 vid.release() 
 # Destroy all the windows 
 cv2.destroyAllWindows() 

track()
```

please some one tell me can I make this

I want to make an app that can control 3d objects with hand gestures

Answer (score 0):

> when ever I am running this both the windows are not opening side by
> side

Simply like this:

Snippet:

```
def run():
    app.run():
    tracker.track()

if __name__=='main':
    run()
```